# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'dict'

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

```
default_value=input("Please enter the trignometric operation u would like to perform : ")

import math



trignometry_tables={

    "sin 0"      : 0,
    "sin 30"     : 1/2,
    "sin 45"     : 1/math.sqrt(2),
    "sin 60"     : math.sqrt(3)/2,
    "sin 90"     : 1,
    "cos 0"      : 1,
    "cos 30"     : math.sqrt(3)/2,
    "cos 45"     : 1/math.sqrt(2),
    "cos 60"     : 1/2,
    "cos 90"     : 0,
    "tan 0"      : 0,
    "tan 30"     : 1/math.sqrt(3),
    "tan 45"     : 1,
    "tan 60"     : math.sqrt(3),
    "tan 90"     : "not defined",
    "cosec 0"    : "not defined",
    "cosec 30"   : 2,
    "cosec 45"   : math.sqrt(2),
    "cosec 60"   : 2/math.sqrt(3),
    "cosec 90"   : 1,
    "sec 0"      : 1,
    "sec 30"     : 2/math.sqrt(3),
    "sec 45"     : math.sqrt(2),
    "sec 60"     : 2 ,
    "sec 90"     : "not defined",
    "cotan 0"    : "not defined",
    "cotan 30"   : math.sqrt(3),
    "cotan 45"   : 1,
    "cotan 60"   : 1/math.sqrt(3),
    "cotan 90"   : 0

}





if default_value=="sin" :


    opposite=input("Please enter the opposite value :")

    for values in trignometry_tables:
        opposite=trignometry_tables
            
    

    hypotnuse=input("Please enter the hypotnuse value :")
    cal=float(opposite)/float(hypotnuse)

    print(cal)
```

Now the let me explain what I want  :

Now when I type for example "sin 0" in the opposite I would like the program to go back
to the dictionary(for here it is that trignometry_table) and find the value which I have assigned it to. And simply just substitute that value for example instead of that sin 0 I would like to get that assigned value 0 and calculate it

Comment: Are you asking about how to access elements of a dictionary? Why are you setting opposite equal to the dictionary?

Comment: @RichardKYu yep but solved it myself took me some time to just get the idea :). thanks for dropping by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved code :

```
default_value=input("Please enter the trignometric operation u would like to perform : ")
    
    import math
    
    
    
    trignometry_tables={
    
        "sin 0"      : 0,
        "sin 30"     : 1/2,
        "sin 45"     : 1/math.sqrt(2),
        "sin 60"     : math.sqrt(3)/2,
        "sin 90"     : 1,
        "cos 0"      : 1,
        "cos 30"     : math.sqrt(3)/2,
        "cos 45"     : 1/math.sqrt(2),
        "cos 60"     : 1/2,
        "cos 90"     : 0,
        "tan 0"      : 0,
        "tan 30"     : 1/math.sqrt(3),
        "tan 45"     : 1,
        "tan 60"     : math.sqrt(3),
        "tan 90"     : "not defined",
        "cosec 0"    : "not defined",
        "cosec 30"   : 2,
        "cosec 45"   : math.sqrt(2),
        "cosec 60"   : 2/math.sqrt(3),
        "cosec 90"   : 1,
        "sec 0"      : 1,
        "sec 30"     : 2/math.sqrt(3),
        "sec 45"     : math.sqrt(2),
        "sec 60"     : 2 ,
        "sec 90"     : "not defined",
        "cotan 0"    : "not defined",
        "cotan 30"   : math.sqrt(3),
        "cotan 45"   : 1,
        "cotan 60"   : 1/math.sqrt(3),
        "cotan 90"   : 0
    
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    if default_value=="sin" :
    
    
        
        opposite=input("Please enter the opposite value :")
    
        for value in trignometry_tables:
            if opposite==value:
                opposite=trignometry_tables.get(value)
         
        hypotnuse=input("Please enter the hypotnuse value :")
    
        
        for value in trignometry_tables:
            if hypotnuse==value:
                hypotnuse=trignometry_tables.get(value)
    
        cal=float(opposite)/float(hypotnuse)
        print(float(cal))
```

okay solved my own problem myself involved some tinkering around so all u need to do is basically use a for loop to go through the entire dictionary in search of the value once it is entered in the opposite input. So if the value entered in the opposite is equal to the any of the keys in the dictionary it will get the value of the specific key.

:) cheers

Comment: Also, it is ineffecient to run a for loop on dictionary, when you want a conditional check for keys. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if default_value=="sin" :


    opposite=input("Please enter the opposite value :")

    opposite=trignometry_tables.get(opposite) 
            
    

    hypotnuse=input("Please enter the hypotnuse value :")
    hypotnuse=trignometry_tables.get(hypotnuse)
    cal=float(opposite)/float(hypotnuse)

    print(cal)
```

Does it help?

Note: You also need to look for Division by Zero and how to handle "not defined" values.

Comment: well no it just returns the output as 0 but thanks for helping anyway and one question how can u get a value when it is not even in the dictionary ?

Comment: @somecoder, what input values did you pass?

Comment: @somecoder, I updated code. Other value also needed to get from dictionary. Read about dictionary get method, you will see how to use it when value not in the dictionary. Thanks

Comment: Yeah I finally got the idea thanks for your help and time :)

Comment: Sorry just now hit me after my internet research the answer you have posted is not relevant to the question and but thanks for dropping here to give your thoughts they are appreciated and I solved my own problem XD thanks again. The fault was with me for not explaining the question properly.